# parallel mediation with more than 2 mediators

Tags: r, regression

i am an absolute noob when it comes to R programming but, alas, I have a college course I have to attend (and pass) and i am really, coming from social sciences, struggling. we're doing this assignment where we have to do a parallel mediation model/analysis with more than 2 mediators, dataset of choice (i have a dataset but in class we've only done it with one mediator)... any nice soul that could help out with an "for dummies" r script? i have this script from the lectures but struggling to replicate it with more mediators... I get the basic condition influences result, condition influences mediator than by doing so the result but not with two more mediators. much obliged to anyone willing to help. i suck at this, i know

### read in "pmi.sav" data and

## assign a name to that dataset as "sample.data2"
  sample.data2 <- read_spss("pmi.sav")
  sample.data2 <- data.table(sample.data2)

## regression predicting reported reactions
  model1 <- lm(reaction ~ cond, data = sample.data2)
  summary(model1)

model.M <- lm(pmi ~ cond, data = sample.data2)
  model.Y <- lm(reaction ~ cond + pmi, data = sample.data2)
  summary(model.M)
  summary(model.Y)

## sobel test
  ## model.M = regression model predicting mediator, with "apath" being the name of the IV
  ## model.Y = regression model predicting DV, with "bpath" being the name of the mediator
  sobel.test <- function(model.M, apath, model.Y, bpath) {
    a <- coef(model.M)[apath]
    sa <- summary(model.M)$coef[apath, 2]
b <- coef(model.Y)[bpath]
sb <- summary(model.Y)$coef[bpath, 2]
    indirect <- a*b

```
z <- indirect/sqrt(b^2*sa^2 + a^2*sb^2 + sa^2*sb^2)
pval <- 2*pnorm(-abs(z));

return(c(indirect = indirect, z = z, pval = pval))
```

}

sobel.test(model.M, "cond", model.Y, "pmi")

## 10,000 resample example
  ## function to get empirical indirect effect
  indirect.effect <- function(model.M, apath, model.Y, bpath) {
    a <- coef(model.M)[apath]
    b <- coef(model.Y)[bpath]

```
indirect <- a*b
indirect
```

}

indirect.effect(model.M, "cond", model.Y, "pmi")

rep.indirect <- sapply(1:10000, function(i) {
    resample <- sample.data2[sample(1:123, replace = T), ]
    model.M.resample <- lm(formula(model.M), data = resample)
    model.Y.resample <- lm(formula(model.Y), data = resample)
    indirect.effect(model.M.resample, "cond", model.Y.resample, "pmi")
  }, simplify = "array")

quantile(rep.indirect, c(0.025, 0.975))

## plot for 10,000 replication of indirect effects
  hist(rep.indirect, breaks = 100, col = "gray", main = "", xlab = "Indirect effects")
  abline(v = quantile(rep.indirect, 0.025), col = "red", lty = 2) ## red dotted (lty = 2) line, lower 95th percentile
  abline(v = quantile(rep.indirect, 0.975), col = "red", lty = 2) ## red dotted (lty = 2) line, upper 95th percentile

## ------------------------ ##
  ## indirect effect est in R ##
  ## ------------------------ ##

## function to get empirical indirect effect
  indirect.effect <- function(model.M, apath, model.Y, bpath) {
    a <- coef(model.M)[apath]
    b <- coef(model.Y)[bpath]

```
indirect <- a*b
indirect
```

}

indirect.effect(model.M, "cond", model.Y, "pmi")

## function to make inferecences for indirect effect
  boot.indirect <- function(data, i, model.M, apath, model.Y, bpath) {

```
## resample data n times
resample <- data[i,]

## refit regression model on resampled data
model.M.resample <- lm(formula(model.M), data = resample)
model.Y.resample <- lm(formula(model.Y), data = resample)

a <- coef(model.M.resample)[apath] ## a path
b <- coef(model.Y.resample)[bpath] ## b path
c <- coef(model.Y.resample)[apath] ## c path

## effect decomposition
## indirect effect
indirect.boot <- a*b
direct.boot <- c
return(c(direct.boot = direct.boot, indirect.boot = indirect.boot))
```

}

require(boot)
  boot_indirect_effect <- boot(data = sample.data2,
                               statistic = boot.indirect,
                               model.M = "model.M", apath = "cond",
                               model.Y = "model.Y", bpath = "pmi",
                               R = 5000,
                               parallel = "multicore",
                               ncpus = 8)

## inference for direct and indirect effect
  boot.ci(boot_indirect_effect, index = 1, type = "perc")
  boot.ci(boot_indirect_effect, index = 2, type = "perc")

## more complex model
  ## Model of M1
  model.m1 <- lm(pmi ~ cond + gender + age, data = sample.data2)
  summary(model.m1)

## Model of M2
  model.m2 <- lm(import ~ cond + gender + age, data = sample.data2)
  summary(model.m2)

## Model of Y
  model.Y <- lm(reaction ~ cond + pmi + import + 
                  gender + age, data = sample.data2)
  summary(model.Y)

## custom function for inference
  boot.indirect2 <- function(data, i) {

```
## resample data based on index i
resample.data <- data[i, ]

## re-estimate the regression models 
model.m1.resample <- lm(formula(model.m1), data = resample.data)
model.m2.resample <- lm(formula(model.m2), data = resample.data)
model.Y.resample <- lm(formula(model.Y), data = resample.data)

## extract coefficients and compute indirect effects
a1 <- coef(model.m1.resample)["cond"]
a2 <- coef(model.m2.resample)["cond"]
b1 <- coef(model.Y.resample)["pmi"]
b2 <- coef(model.Y.resample)["import"]
c <- coef(model.Y.resample)["cond"]

indirect_pmi <- a1*b1
indirect_import <- a2*b2
direct <- c

## output vector, name - values
out <- c(indirect_pmi = indirect_pmi,
         indirect_import = indirect_import,
         total_indirect = indirect_pmi + indirect_import,
         direct = direct)
return(out)
```

}

boot_indirect_effect2 <- boot(data = sample.data2,
                               statistic = boot.indirect2,
                               R = 10000,
                               parallel = "multicore",
                               ncpus = 8)

## inference for direct and indirect effect
  boot.ci(boot_indirect_effect2, index = 1, type = "perc")
  boot.ci(boot_indirect_effect2, index = 2, type = "perc")
  boot.ci(boot_indirect_effect2, index = 3, type = "perc")

## comparing two specific indirect effects
  boot_indirect_effect2$t0[1] - boot_indirect_effect2$t0[2]
  test <- boot_indirect_effect2$t[,1] - boot_indirect_effect2$t[,2]
  quantile(test, c(0.025, 0.975))

## Multicategorical variables
  ## read in "web.sav" data and 
  ## assign a name to that dataset as "sample.data3"
  sample.data3 <- read_spss("web.sav")

multicat.model <- lm(attitude ~ d1 + d2, data = sample.data3)
  summary(multicat.model)

multicat.model.M <- lm(inter ~ d1 + d2, data = sample.data3)
  multicat.model.Y <- lm(attitude ~ d1 + d2 + inter, data = sample.data3)
  summary(multicat.model.M)
  summary(multicat.model.Y)

boot.indirect.multicat <- function(data, i) {

```
## resample data
resample.data <- data[i, ]

## re-estimate model of M and Y based on resampled data
multicat.M.rspl <- lm(formula(multicat.model.M), data = resample.data)
multicat.Y.rspl <- lm(formula(multicat.model.Y), data = resample.data)

## recover coefficients
a1 <- coef(multicat.M.rspl)["d1"]
a2 <- coef(multicat.M.rspl)["d2"]
b <- coef(multicat.Y.rspl)["inter"]
cp1 <- coef(multicat.Y.rspl)["d1"]
cp2 <- coef(multicat.Y.rspl)["d2"]

## effect decomposition
relative.ind.d1 <- a1*b
relative.ind.d2 <- a2*b
relative.direct.d1 <- cp1
relative.direct.d2 <- cp2

out <- c(relative.ind.d1 = relative.ind.d1,
         relative.ind.d2 = relative.ind.d2,
         relative.direct.d1 = relative.direct.d1,
         relative.direct.d2 = relative.direct.d2)

return(out)
```

}

boot_indirect_effect3 <- boot(data = sample.data3,
                                statistic = boot.indirect.multicat,
                                R = 10000,
                                parallel = "multicore",
                                ncpus = 8)

## inference for direct and indirect effect
  boot_indirect_effect3$t0
  boot.ci(boot_indirect_effect3, index = 1, type = "perc")
  boot.ci(boot_indirect_effect3, index = 2, type = "perc")
  boot.ci(boot_indirect_effect3, index = 3, type = "perc")
  boot.ci(boot_indirect_effect3, index = 4, type = "perc")

## omnibus test of total effect
    ## total effect model without no group dummies
    multicat.model.null <- lm(attitude ~ 1, data = sample.data3)
    summary(multicat.model.null)
    ## total effect model with group dummies (we already have it)
    summary(multicat.model)

```
## changes in R-sq (as a whole)
summary(multicat.model)$r.squared - summary(multicat.model.null)$r.squared
## anova (whether R-sq change is significant?)
anova(multicat.model, multicat.model.null)
```

## omnibus test of direct effect
    ## direct effect model without no group dummies
    multicat.model.null2 <- lm(attitude ~ inter, data = sample.data3)
    summary(multicat.model.null2)
    ## direct effect model with group dummies (we already have it)
    summary(multicat.model.Y)

```
## changes in R-sq (as a whole)
summary(multicat.model.Y)$r.squared - summary(multicat.model.null2)$r.squared
## anova (whether R-sq change is significant?)
anova(multicat.model.null2, multicat.model.Y)
```

## omnibus test of indirect effect
  boot.omnibus.multicat <- function(data, i) {

```
## resample data
resample.data <- data[i, ]

## re-estimate model of M and Y based on resampled data
multicat.M.null.rspl <- lm(inter ~ 1, data = resample.data)
multicat.M.rspl <- lm(formula(multicat.model.M), data = resample.data)
multicat.Y.rspl <- lm(formula(multicat.model.Y), data = resample.data)

## recover quantity of interest
rsq.change <- summary(multicat.M.rspl)$r.squared - summary(multicat.M.null.rspl)$r.squared
b <- coef(multicat.Y.rspl)["inter"]

omnibus.indirect.multicat <- rsq.change*b

return(omnibus.indirect.multicat)
```

}

boot_omnibus.test <- boot(data = sample.data3,
                                statistic = boot.omnibus.multicat,
                                R = 10000,
                                parallel = "multicore",
                                ncpus = 8)

## inference for direct and indirect effect
  boot_omnibus.test$t0
  boot.ci(boot_omnibus.test, index = 1, type = "perc")